# Integrating PayPal Button to my React app

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal payment button to my React.js application. I'm using react-paypal-js library (https://github.com/paypal/react-paypal-js) to achieve it. Thing is, this library has little documentation and I don't understand the following:

1. how to send to PayPal product name and price of bought product
2. how to receive response from PayPal on whether the product is bought, the transaction is canceled etc
   Can you please help me understand how to do it?
   Here's my PayPal payment form component:

```js
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

export default function PaypalPaymentForm() {
    const initialOptions = {
        "client-id": "test",
        currency: "EUR",
        intent: "capture",
        "data-client-token": "abc123xyz==",
    };
    return (
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
            <PayPalButtons style={{ layout: "horizontal" }} />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but you need to define createOrder and onApprove functions, which can be client side or can be fetches to your server.   Have you looked at the Storybook? https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default